# create an Array in android studio with google maps API to store markers

Tags: android, arrays, google-maps

I would really appreciate some help with this problem. I have tried many different solutions i'v found on here and none of them seem to work for me. I have a google map activity in my app on android studio. Currently my users can click on the map to drop pins. The code for that is as follows.

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

    // Creating a marker
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

    // Setting the position for the marker
    markerOptions.position(latLng);

    // Setting the title for the marker.
    // This will be displayed on taping the marker
    markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + " : " + latLng.longitude);

    // Animating to the touched position
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Placing a marker on the touched position
    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        }
    });
```

What i require is the lat and long for each marker dropped to be saved into an array. It will be possible for the users to drop as many pins as they require. I have tried to implement this with a for loop but i have had no luck. If someone could show me how to set up the array and save all the information into it it would be greatly appreciated.

Regards Peakapot

Comment: Declare a `private List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<>();` and add the `Marker`s to it doing `markers.add(mMap.addMarker(markerOptions));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i implemented such functionality in my project where i store Marker latitude, longitude, title in Shared preferences and load them from the stored value.

Declare variables

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
int locationCount = 0;
```

initialize your sharedPreferences:

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("location", 0);
```

Now use this method to store marker Values:

```
public void Save_marker(Marker m) {
    //pass market object as parameter
    ++locationCount;
    /** Opening the editor object to write data to sharedPreferences */
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    // Storing the latitude for the i-th location
    editor.putString("lat" + Integer.toString((locationCount - 1)), Double.toString(m.getPosition().latitude));

    // Storing the longitude for the i-th location
    editor.putString("lng" + Integer.toString((locationCount - 1)), Double.toString(m.getPosition().longitude));

    // Storing the count of locations or marker count
    editor.putInt("locationCount", locationCount);
    editor.putString("title", m.getTitle());
    /** Saving the values stored in the shared preferences */
    editor.commit();
}
```

Now for getting the stored Marker values you can use:

```
public void Get_markers() {
    String title_name = "";
    Integer image_icon = R.drawable.currentlocation_icon; //marker icon for map
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("location", 0);
    // Getting number of locations already stored
    locationCount = sharedPreferences.getInt("locationCount", 0);
    String[] location_name = new String[locationCount];
    if (locationCount != 0) {

        String lat = "";
        String lng = "";

        // Iterating through all the locations stored
        for (int i = 0; i < locationCount; i++) {
            // Getting the latitude of the i-th location
            lat = sharedPreferences.getString("lat" + i, "0");
            title_name = sharedPreferences.getString("title", "");
            // Getting the longitude of the i-th location
            lng = sharedPreferences.getString("lng" + i, "0");
            location_name[i] = title_name;
            // Drawing marker on the map
            drawMarker(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng)), title_name);
        }


private void drawMarker(LatLng point, String title_marker) {
    // Creating an instance of MarkerOptions
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    // Setting latitude and longitude for the marker
    markerOptions.position(point);
    // Adding marker on the Google Map
    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
   //here mMap is your google map object
}
```

for full implementation see this link:
http://www.androidtrainee.com/adding-multiple-marker-locations-in-google-maps-android-api-v2-and-save-it-in-shared-preferences/

Comment: @Peakapot if it works..don't forget to accept and upvote the answer..thnks

Comment: I have upvoted the answer but becuase of my low reputation it doesn't show up. I need to get above 15 first. That's going to be pretty difficult when people down vote me for simply asking a question. Again thank you for taking the time to help me out. Appreciated.

Comment: I will do mate.

Comment: No mate. drawMarker and point couldn't be resolved. Tried to get it to work for a while. I couldn't get it.